# Rounding Percentages

Tags: computer-science, percentages

Okay so I have been having a problem and would really appreciate any help.
I have posted a table below with the aim of making this as simple/precise as possible.

```
Value          %              Rounded %     Direction
10     1.515151515151520%       2%              Up
20     3.030303030303030%       3%             Down
30     4.545454545454550%       5%              Up
40     6.060606060606060%       6%             Down
50     7.575757575757580%       8%              Up
60     9.090909090909090%       9%             Down
70    10.606060606060600%      11%              Up
80    12.121212121212100%      12%             Down
90    13.636363636363600%      14%              Up
100   15.151515151515200%      15%             Down
110   16.666666666666700%      17%              Up
T660        102%
```

Table explanation:
Value is a number (total=660). The % is the percentage of the total ((value/660)*100%). Rounded is the % rounded at the percentage level rather than rounding the total. Direction is whether the rounding is up or down. 
(row begining with T, = Totals)

Problem:
**I understand why I am getting 102%**. I am creating a report that uses percentages and I want the rounded percentages to add up to 100% but be as mathematically accurate as possible. 
Is it possible to determine which decimals in the % column are most significant to the overall increase in the total percentage? 
Is there some universal equation that can be derived to perform this?

I know that this is pretty vague, so please comment if you need any clarification, but any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Also, just throwing it out there, your life would be much easier if you kept two decimal places. Then if you rounded, it would come out to 100.02. If you didn't, it would come out to 99.96. Do you think your report really needs whole number percentages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483430/how-to-make-rounded-percentages-add-up-to-100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you cannot do this and get the rounding correctly done. However, one possible method is the following:

Calculate the roundoff error, so for $1.515 \dots$ to $2$ the roundoff error is: $$|2 - 1.515...| = 0.4949\dots$$For the second entry, it would be: $$|3-3.0303\dots|=0.0303\dots$$ After you've done this for each entry, do the following:

**If the total rounded percentage is greater than 100%**: Find the entry with the largest error that rounds *up*, and change it so that it rounds down. A large error means it is close to the limit of being rounded down.

**If the total rounded percentage is less than 100%**: Find the entry with the largest error that rounds *down*, and change it so that it rounds up.

**Repeat** the above process until the rounded percentage is exactly $100 \%$.

(You could also do this algorithm with *relative* error, instead of *absolute* error.)